# OSGi/Felix Declarative Services: How to filter the services to be bound?

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, osgi, apache-felix

I am using Apache Felix and its Declarative Services (SCR) to wire the service dependencies between bundles.

For example, if I need access to a java.util.Dictionary I can say the following to have SCR provide one:

```
/**
* @scr.reference name=properties interface=java.util.Dictionary
*/

protected void bindProperties(Dictionary d) {
}

protected void unbindProperties(Dictionary d) {
}
```

Now, I have more than one Dictionary service available, and I want to filter them using the "name" service property (I only want "name=myDictionary"). I can do that with code (using a ServiceTracker), but I'd rather specify the filter in the @scr annotation instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
target="(name=myDictionary)"
```

should do the trick in the `@scr.reference` annotation. See http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

In standard DS, you can use target attribute of the reference element. In Felix world, where annotations can be used, I don't know what is the equivalent.

The target attribute is an LDAP filter, which matches against the service properties. So, your filter should be:

`(name=myDictionary)`

Comment: I think target="(name=myDictionary)" should do the trick in the @scr.reference annotation. See http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html